# Showing showbreak character at the end of the line that is wrapping

Tags: vimrc, wrapping, line-breaks

Is there a way to show `showbreak` character at the end of the line that is wrapping, not at the beginning of the next one?

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor \
   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna \
   aliqua.
2. Ut enim ad minim veniam...
```

Where `\` represent these `showbreak` characters.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3):

According to `:help showbreak`

> String to put at the start of lines that have been wrapped.

this seems to not be possible. (As the character is not really a part of the buffer even some elaborate function will not help)